# Ruby custom method to fill hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm working on a method that will allow me to add in a "word" and its "definition", into a hash.

Here's what I have:

```
class Dictionary
def entries
 @entries ||= {}

end

def add word, definition = nil
    entries[word] = definition
    "#{entries}"
end

end
```

**Note:** I want the definition parameter to be optional, hence my initialization to nil.  However, for some reason that is showing up in my output.

Example: Passing in "fish" and "aquatic animal":

**My output:** `{{"fish"=>"aquatic animal"}=>nil}`

**Desired output:** `{"fish"=>"aquatic animal"}`

It seems like the problem is that it's putting both values that I pass to the method into the first key in the hash, and is putting that "nil" value into that key's value.  Where am I making an error?

**Edit:** Adding the relevant RSpec block that is doing the method call so that I can better understand exactly how RSpec is making this call:

```
describe Dictionary do
  before do
    @d = Dictionary.new
  end

  it 'is empty when created' do
    @d.entries.should == {}
  end

  it 'can add whole entries with keyword and definition' do
    @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
    @d.entries.should == {'fish' => 'aquatic animal'}
    @d.keywords.should == ['fish']
  end
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is working for me.. Show us how you are calling the method.

Comment: @ArupRakshit That's also a piece I'm struggling with.  It's a coding project to learn RSpec, so I'm actually not sure exactly how RSpec is calling the method.  The relevant RSpec lines have been posted above - if you could help me understand this part a bit better as well, I'd be really grateful

Comment: Can you add exactly how you are calling this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to optionally accept a hash entry...

```
def add word, definition = nil
    if word.class == Hash
      entries.merge!(word)
    else
      entries[word] = definition
    end
    "#{entries}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do

```
 @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
```

You want to do...

```
 @d.add('fish', 'aquatic animal')
```

As it is, you're passing a hash as the first argument, second argument is empty.

Comment: Thanks @SteveTurczyn. I'm not able to change the RSpec (it's just a given), but I have to figure out how to handle RSpec's passing in a hash instead of just 2 parameters. Do you have any recommendations on how I can edit my method to handle a hash being passed in as the first parameter?

Comment: Yes, you can, I've added another answer to cover this.

Answer (score 1):

Your RSpec is wrong.

Change `@d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')` to `@d.add('fish', 'aquatic animal')`

Your `#add` method is accepting 2 parameters, with one being optional. With your current code, you're passing in a single hash `'fish' => 'aquatic animal'`. Therefor setting `word` to the hash, and def to `nil`.

Comment: Thanks @Cereal - I had a feeling it was something like this that was going on.  I'm not able to change the RSpec (it's just a given), but I have to figure out how to handle RSpec's passing in a hash instead of just 2 parameters.  Do you have any recommendations on how I can edit my method to handle a hash being passed in as the first parameter?

Comment: You can do a check at the start of the method for a hash. Something like `if word.class == Hash then merge! word` would do what you want. Then do the other functionality in an `else`.